# Why numpy stops reading a complete list?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new on programming. I am writing a python code to read a file.txt composed by 4 columns and 800 of rows. The first column refers to abscise of some route data. There are some duplicates on the abscises, so I am eliminating them by calculating the difference between one abscise respect to one before. Those differences resulting equal to zero are taken out. Then I create a new file with the data without duplicates. Everything works fine, except that after running the code, it seems that it does read all of the lines, stopping by the 600th row without announcing any errors. This is the code:

```
ruta = 7008
dbtxt = np.loadtxt('../Datos/tables/IN/R' +"%s" % (ruta) +'_txt.txt', 
dtype='float', delimiter='\t') 
d_ant = dbtxt[0,0]
x_ant = dbtxt[0,1]
y_ant = dbtxt[0,2]
z_ant = dbtxt[0,3]
absc = dbtxt[1:,0]
x_coor = dbtxt[1:,1]
y_coor = dbtxt[1:,2]
z_coor = dbtxt[1:,3] 
file_out_ida =open('../datos/tables/IN/R'+"%s" %(ruta)+'_clean3.txt',"w")
file_out_ida.write("absc\tX_coor\tY_coor\tZ_coor\n")
file_out_ida.write(str(d_ant)+
    "\t"+str(x_ant)+"\t"+str(y_ant)+"\t"+str(z_ant)+"\n")

for d_act, x_act, y_act, z_act in zip(absc, x_coor, y_coor, z_coor):

    denomin = d_act-d_ant`

    if denomin == 0:
        d_ant = d_act
        x_ant = x_act
        y_ant = y_act
        z_ant = z_act
    else:
        file_out_ida.write(str(d_act)+
        "\t"+str(x_act)+"\t"+str(y_act)+"\t"+str(z_act)+\n")
        d_ant = d_act
        x_ant = x_act
        y_ant = y_act
        z_ant = z_act

file_out_ida.close
```

I wonder if I am missing something to let it read the 800 rows.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked if that particular row is in some way ill-formed? (weird characters, extra separators?

Comment: Yes I did, but it is fine.

Comment: "it seems that it stops..." can you elaborate on how you came to that conclusion? maybe 200 lines fit the requirement denomin == 0? By the way: you should rewrite that ifstatement, its redundant. Just say "if not denomin == 0: filue_out..." and put the other 4 statements outside after that.

Comment: @Banana The abscises on the original file go until 8388 (meters) and the second file stops by 7592. Until there, all the abscises are without duplicates but it is not finished yet. Thanks for the other suggestion. Do ou know if I can share the original file.txt some how?

Comment: I unfortunately dont know any file sharing (and stackoverflows policy on that) but maybe you can try to reproduce the error with just a few lines (try the critical line plus/minus 2). If that works, you can post the lines and we can try to verify it. Edit: Googled for a second, some SO post says try http://filedropper.com - but you should try to reproduce it with a few lines first, nonetheless.